# How to push value into array after every loop?

Tags: php

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$Product=$data->Product;

$items = array();
print_r($items);
foreach($Product as $index => $value)
{
        $Product1 = $Product[$index];
        array_push($items, $Product1);
}
```

I need to push `$Product1` value into the array for every iteration. How do I do this?

Comment: `$items[] = $value;`

Comment: Even more simple: why don't you simply use `array_column()`?

Comment: I used $items[] = $Product1; also. it is not working @ IcedAnt

Comment: could you please explain how to use array_column()? @ arkascha

Comment: `$items = $data->Product` is the same. YOu're just putting values from one array to another without changing.

Comment: Remove everything else from inside your loop and just use it as I wrote it

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working? IcedAnt's answer should work fine. post any errors you get + why are you storing `$Product[$index]` in `$Product1`? you can directly access it, unnecessary waste of memory.

Comment: @IcedAnt `array_push($items, $value);` already should exactly do this. It isnot clear at all, what the question is.

Comment: @konda It is better to actually post what are you trying to achieve, we may have a better approach that is easy and do not take much resource

Comment: i try to push every $Product1 value into array. if  $Product1 is not in array i have to pass DB query. if it is in no query

Comment: It's still not clear, **update your question** with the details and a sample of `$Product1` and a sample of the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);// ensure you don't get an std-class object
$Product=$data->Product;

$items = array();
//print_r($items); // you will always print an empty array if you put it here
foreach($Product as $index => $value)
{
    $Product1 = $Product[$index];
    echo $Product1; // for debug reasons
    $items[]=$Product1;
}
echo '<pre>'; //just for the array format
print_r($items);  //for debug reasons
```

This code should fill the array `$items` with the values you need. Read my comments as well please, maybe we could help more if you gave us the debugging results but still this code should work for you.

Comment: How is this the accepted answer? Not that there's anything wrong with it but you could just have skipped the loop and just done `print_r($Product);`

Comment: The "trick" from what i am aware is in the json_decode(,true). If you don't decode a json like this it returns an std-class object that is not accessible as an array. So that's where it was bugging.